Storing recorded video files on Google Drive using Rclone
I am working on an application that records videos and saves them locally on my PC. However, I want to store these recordings directly on Google Drive instead of saving them locally. I am using Rclone to manage this process.
Here is the issue: When I stop the recording, the file is currently saved locally, but I want it to be uploaded to Google Drive. Although I have configured Rclone and written the code, I am encountering a 404 Not Found error when attempting to upload the file.
Code:
RoomClient.js
async handleLocalRecordingStop() {
    console.log('MediaRecorder Blobs: ', recordedBlobs);

    const dateTime = getDataTimeString();
    const type = recordedBlobs[0].type.includes('mp4') ? 'mp4' : 'webm';
    const blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, { type: 'video/' + type });
    const recFileName = `Rec_${dateTime}.${type}`;
    const currentDevice = DetectRTC.isMobileDevice ? 'MOBILE' : 'PC';
    const blobFileSize = bytesToSize(blob.size);
    const recTime = document.getElementById('recordingStatus');
    const recType = 'Locally';
    const recordingInfo = `
    <br/><br/>
    <ul>
        <li>Stored: ${recType}</li>
        <li>Time: ${recTime.innerText}</li>
        <li>File: ${recFileName}</li>
        <li>Codecs: ${recCodecs}</li>
        <li>Size: ${blobFileSize}</li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    `;
    const recordingMsg = `Please wait to be processed and uploaded to your Google Drive.`;

    this.saveLastRecordingInfo(recordingInfo);
    this.showRecordingInfo(recType, recordingInfo, recordingMsg);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', blob, recFileName);

    try {
        const response = await fetch('/upload-to-drive', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        });
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('Recording uploaded to Google Drive successfully');
        } else {
            console.log('Failed to upload recording file to Google Drive');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error during file upload to Google Drive', error);
    }
}

Server.js
const multer = require('multer');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');

   const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }); 

    app.post('/upload-to-drive', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
        const file = req.file;
        const destination = 'singervoice:testfolder/' + file.originalname;
    
        // Use rclone to upload to Google Drive
        const command = `rclone move ${file.path} ${destination}`;
        exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`rclone error: ${error}`);
                return res.status(500).send('Upload failed');
            }
            console.log(`rclone output: ${stdout}`);
            res.send('Upload successful');
        });
        
    });



Expected: The recorded video file should be uploaded to Google Drive when recording stops.
Actual: I receive a 404 Not Found error when trying to upload the file.

